# Djanog Filter by field values of the reverse reference model of 1:N relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models

The `Branch` and `Subsidy` models have a 1:N relationship,
In the `Subsidy` model, the 'related_name' of the branch field is set to 'subsidy'.

I'm trying to filter the `Branch` query set with the 'price' field value of `Subsidy`, but I get the following error.

```py
Branch.objects.filter(subsidy__price__gt=0)
```

> Cannot resolve keyword 'subsidy' into field. Choices are: brand_idx, idx, is_active, name, order, province_idx, sido, sido_id

As shown below, individual instances seem to have good access to the related_name called 'subsidy', but I don't know why I couldn't find the field "subsidy" when filtering the query set.

```py
Branch.objects.get(idx=1).subsidy.all()
```

- my models.py

```py
class Branch(models.Model):
    idx = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
    province_idx = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    sido = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='sigungu')
    brand_idx = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.IntegerField(default=1, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.province_idx:
            self.sido_id = self.province_idx
        else:
            self.sido_id = 0
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'branch'

class Subsidy(models.Model):
    idx = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, db_column='car_idx', related_name='car_subs')
    lineup = models.ForeignKey(Lineup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, db_column='lineup_idx', related_name='lineup_subs')
    trim = models.ForeignKey(Trim, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, db_column='trim_idx', related_name='trim_subs')
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True, blank=True, related_name='subsidy')
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    is_state = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    month = models.DateField(default=None, null=True)
    is_block = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'subsidy'
```

Comment: tried without Meta classes and sido field. The data is being retrieved.